# Cache Yum downloads via squid proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, yum, squid, rhel

I have installed Squid and configured Yum to use it as a proxy - this works when fetching repo data - I can see it in the Squid access logs.

```
[root@box tmp]# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
epel | 3.6 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db | 3.8 MB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-5 | 1.4 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-5/primary | 5.4 MB     00:01

[root@box~]# tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log
1375408719.219    915 10.0.0.22 TCP_MISS/200 643 GET http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist? - DIRECT/66.35.62.166 text/plain
1375408719.514      0 10.0.0.22 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 4091 GET http://mirror.iprimus.com.au/epel/5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml - NONE/- text/xml
1375408719.893     45 10.0.0.22 TCP_HIT/200 3982344 GET http://mirror.iprimus.com.au/epel/5/x86_64/repodata/6964aae8cc07d55241680cec98f79908a810454e-primary.sqlite.bz2 - NONE/- application/x-bzip
```

But when I actually do a yum install or update a package, there is no indication that this is going through the proxy (it still works, but I would like to cache the data so it can be used by others on the network)

In my /etc/yum.conf I have proxy=http://domain.com:3128 and I have also set the global $http_proxy variable (wget http://www.google.com successfully uses this proxy variable)

Any ideas? I'm guessing yum isn't using http to do the downloads??

Comment: This is not a Programming related question. You should better ask on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

Agree, this should be in serverfault.

In answer to your question, though:
You'll need to comment out `mirrorlist=` in yum.repos.d/*.repo and uncomment/edit `baseurl=` - yum's rotating mirrors cause squid to cache the package multiple times, so you have to work around this behavior by specifying only a single mirror.